# Unusual digit classificaion with DNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been thinking of this problem for some time now, and I haven't found an answer I'm quite happy with.

Imagine we've trained a DNN on MNIST database of digits that classifies out-of-sample observations with some high precision. Then we show the DNN the unusual image of 4 and 3 like below. Will the DNN classify it correctly? I don't think so, because the hidden layer simply won't have the features present in the image with unusual digits (various curls), so it will likely to misclassify them.

I also think that training on a database of such unusual digits only would be hard. How will hidden layers store the (very similar) features? Intuitively, it will overfit on this db because the hidden neurons will learn all the unnecessary features due to similarity between the curls.

I think the way to train such a DNN is to somehow learn the angles between 'bars'/curls making up the digits, e.g. in the digit '4' there is a straight angle between the bars, but I'm not too sure. I also couldn't find a paper dealing with this question.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know what the image represented at first or second glance. However, have you tried to classify such digits? You won't know if it's possible unless you try it. Train it on MNIST and create A) a test set by hand that is similar to MNISt - just regular hand written digits, classified, as your control test, and B) a set of some more whacky numbers like this. Compare the classification rate and use A) as a sort of control group. Let me know how it goes! Otherwise, I second user2637126's suggestion: blur the whacky number and MNIST likewise, the overall patterns will come through.

Comment: 'I didn't know what the image represented at first or second glance' - did you read the question? At the very beginning it says 'unusual image of 4 and 3 '

Comment: No, I got that. My point was that I looked at the image before reading the question, and I had to look at them three times before I realised what they were. The fact that that happened means that it is indeed a hard problem.

Comment: We're getting into the realm where ml is better at some recognition tasks than humans - which is exciting! Now days, I find captchas have to be so obscured that, again, I can barely read them. Another example is when doing sentiment analysis on tweets, for instance, the hardest tweets to classify are sarcastic ones. However, real humans also struggle to classify sarcastic comments in text! Another example is in medical imaging, where computer driven annotation of medical images is becoming better than that of medical professionals. I think this is an interesting problem for these reasons :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I think trying to build features that represent angles is not in the spirit of DNNs: the whole point of deep learning is that you do not have any more to design such detailed features manually, but you let the network learns them and discovers the most relevant features for the target task automatically.

For your question, a more "mainstream" approach would rather be to take an existing digits database and corrupt the digit images in such a way that you obtain pictures that resemble your examples. For instance, you may try to replace straight lines of N pixels with random curvatures.

This kind of approach is often used in deep learning to increase the training dataset while at the same time improving the robustness of the network to some kind of noise. Hence, classical corruption methods consist in translating/rotating the images of digits.

But note that for the two pictures you showed, a simpler solution may be to blur or pixelize or reduce the definition, or better compute a spectral transform with clipping, so that the global/larger shape only is captured and the smaller variations are filtered-out.

Comment: 'blur or pixelize' - you mean use the ConvNN?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look to the best results on MNIST, you will see that they all (last time I checked) use an elastic deformation at each epoch during the training.

In your case, you have to add such type of deformation: elastic oscillations (or ?).

If you are sure that you have only this type of information, then you can try to simplify the numbers (main portions of curves instead of these oscillations), and then give it to your DNN.

Comment: 'If you are sure that you have only this type of information' - do you mean the curls?

Comment: Yes for the curls, and here are the elastic deformations I am talking about: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68920/icdar03.pdf

Comment: MNIST results were improved a lot when they added this type of deformation